# symfony2: how to make a form field not required on update

Tags: symfony

I have a form with a file field, I'd like to have this field mandatory only when I create the record, not on update.
in buildForm I only have this for the field:

```
->add('file', 'file', array(
            'required'    => false,
        ))
```

and in the controller I check for the id to decide if insert or update

thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Your form class add:

```
public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
{
    $resolver->setRequired([
        'update',
    ]);
}
```

Then, when you are creating form use this:

```
$form = $this->createForm('formName', $object, array(
            'update' => $entity->getId==null?false:true,
       ));
```

And after that, in your form, in $options array you can use $options['update'].
Eg.:

```
->add('file', 'file', array(
            'required'    => !$options['update'],
        ))
```

Comment: thanks for your reply, what should I use in place of $entity? thanks

Answer (score 2):

The proper way to handle this problem is to use FormEvents http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/dynamic_form_modification.html